# AWS show permission denied when try to change the page content of index.html of Apache

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have created an instance in the AWS EC2.Then I configured Apache on EC2. The Test Page is open successfully. But from the Command Line, when I tried to modify the page content it showed me "*Permission denied*".

In **CMD**, I written the following command:

```
echo "Hello World" > /var/www/html/index.html
```

How could I fix the error of permission denied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html helped me to get my answer. I have followed the commands one by one and got success.

```
sudo groupadd www
sudo usermod -a -G www ec2-user
exit
```

Log back in again and verify that the www group exists with the groups command.

```
groups
ec2-user adm wheel systemd-journal www
sudo chgrp -R www /var/www
sudo chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec sudo chmod 2775 {} +
find /var/www -type f -exec sudo chmod 0664 {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to login to root directory

sudo -i

then try giving the echo command